# Program finding two character pairs but not the third

Tags: java

Writing a practice program that takes a string (in this case "aabccdeef" and returns message "got a pair!" whenever a pair is found.

There are three pairs of characters in the string "aa," "cc," and "ee," yet it is only returning two "got a pair" messages.

I am a hobbyist fairly new to Java so I'm still trying to figure out my way around this. I've attached the code below and would appreciate any help that can be provided, I am more than happy just receiving a hint or general direction.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Here are the pairs of letters in the String next.");
        String next = "aabccdeef";

        for(int i=0; i<next.length()-1; i++){
            if(next.charAt(i) != next.charAt(0)) 
                return; 
                {
                    System.out.println("Got a pair!");
                }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < next.length()-1; i++) {

    if (next.charAt(i) != next.charAt(i+1)) {
        continue;
    }

    System.out.println("Got a pair!");

}
```

Comment: @JessicaChoi you are too polite,I am very happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in the for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < next.length() - 1; i++) {
    if (next.charAt(i) == next.charAt(i+1)) {
        System.out.println("Got a pair!");
    }
}
```

However the above will work only if the similar characters are consecutive. 
To make it work for other cases you should use a nested for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < next.length() - 1; i++) {
    for(int j = i+1; j < next.length(); j++) {
         if (next.charAt(i) == next.charAt(j)) {
             System.out.println("Got a pair!");
         }
    }
}
```

Again the above is still not the most efficient way to do it. The optimal way to do it will be to use a `Set`.